# How to "git add -all", but limit it to maximum 100 at a time?

Tags: linux, git

There are about 3000 files that I need to commit to a repo. Most are images. My problem is if I do what I normally do:

```
git add --all
```

... then I can't push because the git server has various limits that it just keeps hitting. I tried adding workarounds for these limits, but the truth is, I don't normally do such big commits, so I would prefer to not change the settings.

Instead I was hoping there is a way to ONLY add the first 100 untracked files and then stop. Then I can do a "git commit" and a "git push" and all should be well with the world.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have bash available, this should work: list all untracked files, select the first 100 to pass to `git add` as argument.

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | head -n 100 | xargs git add
```

Comment: The piping didn't work as I was hoping it would, but I managed to do this --> git ls-files --others --exclude-standard > allfiles.txt ... and then I was able to get use the file to add it all. Thank you sir! :)

Comment: Had a problem with spaces in file names, useful to use sed: `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | sed "s/^/'/;s/$/'/" | head -n 100 | xargs git add`